# Public member 'Where' on type 'PlcBlockUserGroupComposition' not found

Tags: vb.net, plc

I am trying to locate a folder within a Siemens TIA Portal project using a Vb.Net program with Siemens Openness.

If I run the code:

```
Dim currFolder 'Define the current folder without a type.
currFolder = emptySoftware.BlockGroup

For Each folderName As String In path.Split({"\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    currFolder = currFolder.Groups().Where(Function(x) x.Name = folderName).Single()
Next
```

I get the error

> Public member 'Where' on type 'PlcBlockUserGroupComposition' not found

But the type `SW.Blocks.PlcBlockUserGroup` does implement the interface IEnumerable.

Furthermore, if I run the following code:

```
    Dim currFolder 'Define the current folder without a type.
currFolder = emptySoftware.BlockGroup

For Each folderName As String In path.Split({"\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    Dim tmpFolder = CType(currFolder, SW.Blocks.plcBlockGroup)
    Dim tmp = tmpFolder.Groups
    currFolder = tmpFolder.Groups().Where(Function(x) x.Name = folderName).Single()
Next
```

I get no error, even though my debugger shows that `tmp` is of the type `SW.Blocks.PlcBlockUserGroupComposition`

Why is this? What makes the second snippet work, where the first one doesn't?

The reason I prefer the first snippet, is because this would enable me to use the same code for different types, which all implement the `Groups` attribute, and the `Where` function.

Comment: @MatSnow You are right, the answer describes very nicely what I need (couldn't find it earlier). Should I close this question?